# calculate on pandas rolling windows data

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-sum

I have some problems with data processing based on a pandas rolling-window using a simple self-built function. I have three columns with values and want to use a simple list comprehension to compute one column out of it for further processing. In my example I simply sum-up the values which produces exactly one value for each window. But it seems that the list comprehension fails...

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter as count`

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(50, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))`

`def my_test(data):
    Abs = [int(np.sqrt(x[0]**2+x[1]**2+x[2]**2)/10) for x in data]
    return sum(Abs)`

`entr =  df.rolling(10).apply(my_test)`

This is the error message I get when executing the function:

```
entr =  df.rolling(10).apply(my_test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tpotrusil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 1207, in apply
    return super(Rolling, self).apply(func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tpotrusil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 856, in apply
    center=False)
  File "C:\Users\tpotrusil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 799, in _apply
    result = np.apply_along_axis(calc, self.axis, values)
  File "C:\Users\tpotrusil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 116, in apply_along_axis
    res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\tpotrusil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 795, in calc
    closed=self.closed)
  File "C:\Users\tpotrusil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 853, in f
    offset, func, args, kwargs)
  File "pandas\_libs\window.pyx", line 1450, in pandas._libs.window.roll_generic (pandas\_libs\window.c:36061)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in my_test
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <listcomp>
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Any idea how I can access the rolling-data?

Comment: Nothing to do with pandas rolling window. What is your function supposed to do? At the moment, `data` is a numpy array  of float values, which makes `x` a float. And you try to address it with `x[0]` etc as if it were a list or an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Convert to a series of lists and then apply this function:

```
def my_test(r):
    return int(np.sqrt(sum(r**2)/10))

dfs = pd.Series(data=[df.loc[x].values for x in df.index], index=df.index)
dfs.apply(my_test).rolling(10).sum()
```